# Starting a countdown with a user input number? (Xcode)

Tags: xcode, uitextfield, user-input, countdown

I am trying to make a countdown that starts at a number that the user inputs but I'm unsure how to make this happen.I have done several attempts and alterations to the code but it did not make any difference.

**My code:**

```
-(IBAction)Start 
{
    mainInt = minutes;
    Timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1 target:self selector:@selector(countDown)
    userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}
```

I have declared 'minutes' as a UITextField so that show represent the number entered by the user yes? or no?

I have also @synthesised *minutes in the .m file

any suggestions of what i can do to make the countdown start at a number entered into the UITextField?

Comment: What you want to achieve ? I am assuming that you want to display the countdown in label which starts from user input and end at 0 ? am I right ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer should work well

```
-(IBAction)Start 
{
    mainInt = [minutes.text integerValue];
    Timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1 target:self selector:@selector(countDown)
    userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}

-(void)countDown
{
    mainInt -=1;
    if (mainInt ==0) 
    {
        [Timer invalidate];
    }
    countDownLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",mainInt];
}
```

**Variables used :**

- `minute` is UITextField object where the user is entering number.
- `mainInt` is of type NSInteger holds the updated counter value.
- `countDownLabel` is object of UILabel which you will be using to display the updated counter.